# Open .cs file in designer view from Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I have a winform project in TFS. Under Source Control Explorer I have checked out the file form1.cs and then right clicked form1.cs and clicked "view". This opens up form1.cs code view. How do I view form1.cs [design]?

Comment: You need to download a whole project and then open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out the individual files will not open up designer view. By checking out the solution, solution explorer will then appear from which design view can be accessed for each form.